# Help with Parent-Child relationship in apex class

Tags: apex, class, parent-to-child

I created the following trigger.

```java
trigger Update_Case_Subject on Case (before insert) {
    for (Case c : trigger.new){
        c.Subject = RecordType.DeveloperName + ' - ' + Account.JA_Account_ID__c + ' - ' + Case.Item_1__c + ' - ';
    }
}
```

The trigger works fine.  It updates the subject field with the 3 values listed.  My problem is I need to create the test for this code.  Below is what I have now.

```java
@isTest
private class Update_Case_Subject_Test_Class {
    static TestMethod void Validate_Update_Case_Subject() {
        Case c = new Case(RecordTypeID = '0125e0000007eOKAAY', AccountID = '0015e00000MgfvVAAR', Item_1__c = 'Trigger');
    
        Test.StartTest();
        insert c;
        Test.StopTest();
    
        //Retrieve the new case
        c = [Select Subject From Case Where ID= :c.ID];
        System.debug('Subject after trigger fired: ' + c.Subject);
    
        System.assertEquals('FO - 500074 - Trigger', c.Subject);
    }
}
```

The test is failing with the error

> Assertion Failed: Expected: FO - 500074 - Trigger, Actual: DeveloperName - JA_Account_ID__c - Trigger.

1. How do I write the code to query the Account parent to get the JA_Account_ID__c value.
2. I don't know where to start to get the RecordType.DeveloperName value.

As a bit of background, the concatenation to build the subject field did work fine in a workflow but the workflow is too far down the order of execution and was not running before creating the case.  I have case assignment rules built to read the RecordType.DeveloperName field in the subject.

I have written plenty of SQL queries but the syntax in here has me a bit stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Values like RecordType.DeveloperName are actually static field references used for dynamic Apex. You need to use the variable name you used (`c`) to access a record's data. In addition, parent and child records are not queried automatically.

```
trigger Update_Case_Subject on Case (before insert) {
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
Map<Id, RecordTypeInfo> typeInfos = sobjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosById();

for (Case c : trigger.new){
  accounts.put(c.AccountId, null);
}
accounts.putAll([select JA_Account_ID__c from account where id in :accounts.keyset()]);
for(Case c: Trigger.new) {
  c.Subject = typeInfos.get(c.RecordTypeId)?.getDeveloperName() + ' - ' + accounts.get(c.AccountId)?.JA_Account_Id__c + ' - '+ c.Item_1__c;
}
}
```

Additional work may be necessary, as I guessed your data types.

Comment: I'm currently mobile, I'll update this answer if there's mistakes when I get home.

Comment: Thanks for that it helped a lot!  The code worked well in UAT but it's having a problem pulling the same account data in PROD.  I thought it was because the ID # I'm using in the test was different but it's not.  I'm going to take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @JTG463 in unit tests, you should always create any data you need. Do not use hard coded Id values. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm